How to prove the asymptotic equivalence of Allen-Cahn PDE to an ODE created using the method of lines?
Consider the PDE system $$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \nabla^2_\mathbf{x} u +f(u), \forall \mathbf{x} \in \Omega, \forall t > 0,$$
with Dirichlet boundary condition on $\partial \Omega$, and an initial function $u(x,0) = u_0(x)$, $\forall \mathbf{x} \in \Omega$. Here $\nabla^2_\mathbf{x}$ is the Laplace operator, and $f$ is a continuous, non-Lipschitz function (usually a third-degree polynomial in $u$).
I want to show that an ODE system $$\dot{\mathbf{\beta}} = -L\mathbf{\beta} + f(\mathbf{\beta}), \forall t > 0\qquad \beta_k(0) = u_0(x_k), \textrm{for } k = 1, 2, \dots \dim{(\beta)},$$ resulting from the application of the method of lines,
where $L$ is the graph-Laplacian is asymptotically convergent to the PDE.
In my example $f(u) = \epsilon^{-2}u(\alpha-u)(u-\theta)$, with $\epsilon, \alpha, \theta > 0$, while $f(\mathbf{\beta}) = \epsilon^{-2}\mathbf{\beta}\circ(\alpha\mathbf{1}-\mathbf{\beta})\circ(\mathbf{\beta}-\theta\mathbf{1})$, where $\circ$ is the elementwise product.
So far, it was easy to see that $\nabla^2_\mathbf{x} u = D_{\mathbb{x}}^2u + \mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2)$, where $D_{\mathbb{x}}^2$ is the discrete Laplace operator, and $\Delta x$ is the spacial sample.
Now, if I denote the approximation error along the $\mathbf{x}_k$ line $e_k(t) = u(\mathbf{x}_k, t) - \beta_k(t)$, the ODE would be asymptotically equivalent to the PDE along these lines if $\|\mathbf{e}(t)\|\to0$ as $\Delta x \to 0$ and $t \to \infty$. As I see it, this proof should be made possible by either Lyapunov stability analysis or Grönwall's inequality analysis.
For this purpose, I chose the discrete $l_2$ norm: $$\|\mathbf{e}(t)\|^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{\mathrm{dim}(\beta)}|e_k(t)|^2$$
If I take the time derivative, I get
$$\frac{d}{dt}\|\mathbf{e}(t)\|^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{\mathrm{dim}(\beta)}\frac{d}{dt}|e_k(t)|^2 = 2\sum_{k=1}^{\mathrm{dim}(\beta)}|e_k(t)|\frac{d}{dt}|e_k(t)| = 2\sum_{k=1}^{\mathrm{dim}(\beta)}e_k(t)\frac{d}{dt}e_k(t).$$
After substitutions from the PDE and ODE, I get
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\|\mathbf{e}(t)\|^2 = -2L \|\mathbf{e}(t)\|^2 + c\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2) + 2\sum_{k=1}^{\mathrm{dim}(\beta)}|f(u(\mathbf{x}_k, t) - f(\beta_k)|^2.$$
The first part is OK, but I either did something wrong, or I don't have the knowledge to deal with non-Lipschitz functions with the last part. There, I can not give an upper approximation.
Of course, I know that the original PDE is bounded, so I can say that $f$ is locally Lipschitz on bounded intervals, but I don't know if the solution of the ODE is bounded since the asymptotic equivalence is not proven yet.
Since I have an engineering background and I'm trying to improve the mathematical side, I may have missed some easy or obvious Theorems that could help in this case.
My question is, how would you approach this problem?
